# How to parse a float number input in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The problem is that I need to input a decimal number, like a float, with right format. 
However, I don't know how can I parse the input to ensure it's really a float. If not, I need to putStrLn "ERR". Assume I have the consecutive input.

As example shown below, what condition can I add after IF to exclude the wrong input format, like 1.2.e!@#$, which I should **give an "ERR" and loop main rather than get an error and exit program immediately.**

```
input <- getLine
if (read input1 :: Float) > 1.0
    then do 
        let result1 = upperbound (read input :: Float)
        let result2 = lowerbound (read input :: Float)
        print result4
        print result3
        main
    else do 
        putStrLn"ERR"
        main
```

Answer (score 6):

`read` is a [partial function](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_functions) - it works only on a subset of the input domain. A better example for a partial function is `head`: it works well on non-empty lists, but will throw an error on an empty list - and you can only handle errors when in the `IO` monad. Partial functions are useful in some cases, but you should generally avoid using them. So like `head`, `read` is an unsafe function - it may fail when the input cannot be parsed.

`read` has a safe alternative: `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`.

```
readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
```

`readMaybe` will never fail - if it can't parse a string, it will return `Nothing`. Handling a `Maybe` value is a simple task and can be done in several ways (`case` expressions, `Data.Maybe` functions, `do` notation and so on). Here's an example using a `case` expression:

```
import Text.Read
...
case (readMaybe input :: Maybe Float) of
  Just f | f > 1.0 -> ...
         | otherwise -> ...
  Nothing -> ...
```

[This article](http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors/) can be helpful in understanding the different ways of error handling in Haskell.

Comment: You method is so effective for my case...You are really help me out man... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Prelude> let s1 = "1.223"
Prelude> let s2 = "1"
Prelude> let s3 = "1.2.e!@#$"
Prelude> read s1 :: Float
1.223
Prelude> read s2 :: Float
1.0
Prelude> read s3 :: Float
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

`read` throws an exception when it can't parse the string. You need to handle that exception.

Comment: Thanks, actually I am the newer for haskell..so I tried to work on the exception handling but I can't figure out the corresponding exception type thing.. So could u please give me an example for handling this exception?

Comment: Actually, in this case using `readMaybe` or `readEither` from `Text.Read` would be simpler. See answer by @Benesh.